# How to set windows forms application useshellexecute to true?

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio-2015

My question is **not** answered by the question [When do we need to set UseShellExecute to True?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255086/when-do-we-need-to-set-useshellexecute-to-true) 
If you think it is, please explain how?

I need to set the useshellexecute to true for my windows form application project before the application process start, but I can not find where in the project I have to make the change?

It's a windows form application project in visual studio 2015.

The main entry point for the application looks like this:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new MainForm());
}
```

Where should I use `ProcessStartInfo` and specify `UseShellExecute` value?

**EDIT:**
Big thank you to Matthew Watson who suggested I change the Environment CurrentDirectory which solved the issue! I will mark your anser as the correct one if you post it as an answer!

Comment: "_…I need to set the useshellexecute to true for my windows form application…_" — That makes absolutely no sense to me.

Comment: When launching my application from it's folder, the working directory path is the folder I launched it from. But when I execute it from a shortcut somewhere the working directory path changes to System32. I googled and found I need to change useshellexecute to true but can not find where / how to change it?

Comment: If you look at the properties for the shortcut for your application, it has a "Start in" settings. I'm guessing that is either empty or pointing to the wrong folder. It should specify the folder that contains your exe.

Comment: How about simply [changing your working directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590097/how-do-i-get-set-a-winforms-applications-working-directory)?

Comment: You could also try putting this at the start of your program: `Environment.CurrentDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;`

Comment: @Matthew Watson who suggested I change the Environment CurrentDirectory which solved the issue! I will mark your anser as the correct one if you post it as an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try putting this at the start of your program:

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

That will ensure that your program's current working directory (CWD) is always set to the same folder as the executable when your program starts up.

I suspect what's happening is that the shortcut you're using has a missing or incorrect folder for its "Start in" property. Fixing that would be another approach (right-click the shortcut, select *Properties* and then the *Shortcut* tab, and enter the correct folder in the *Start in* section.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`ProcessStartInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) and specify `UseShellExecute` value.

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("exepath");
startInfo.Arguments = args; //argument
startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;

Process.Start(startInfo);
```